# Is grpc affected by HTTP/2 rapid reset DoS (CVE-2023-44487)?

Tags: security, grpc

Recently an http2 vulnerability, CVE-2023-44487, was disclosed, and grpc-go was confirmed to be affected. But I haven’t found clear information about if grpc is affected too.

Found a pull request https://github.com/grpc/grpc/commit/6a49e953a4df6ea8aa4378de575b0a7a59421f30 seems to be relevant with this vulnerability.

I'd like to learn if grpc is affected by CVE-2023-44487 or if there's a fix for it.

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to learn if grpc is affected by CVE-2023-44487 or if there's a fix for it.

I assume by 'grpc' you mean 'grpc c++'.
Yes, 1.59.2 and later releases contain the fix - please check [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/cLSPkme9kcY) for details.